# Is it possible to split discussions in Google Groups when someone hits reply, and just changes the subject line?

Tags: google-groups

From what I can tell, if a Google Groups user wants to create a new topic, but instead of logging into the web site or opening a new email and addressing it to the group address, they just hit reply to an old thread and change the subject line, Google Groups will get confused.

For example, you can check out [this thread](http://groups.google.lk/group/sri-lankan-drupallers/browse_thread/thread/51f27ef82fb719bf) (this isn't the thread that really made me ask the question, since the group I was using when I thought to ask is not publicly accessible, but this illustrates the point).

Is it possible to fork off the thread into its own proper discussion, so the web interface doesn't look so confusing?

Comment: It does not appear to be possible. This seems to mirror the way such topic splits were handled on newsgroups, so I suspect it's specifically designed that way.

Answer (score 2):

While it's not possible to achieve that through Google Groups web interface, because it is by design, you can do it if use your Gmail to keep up with the group. You can setup your group to receive e-mail on every post and the by replying to that mail and changing the subject, will force the group to create a new post. So in both places you can see your threads correctly.

Also it's a good idea to create a special filter for it to Skip inbox for example.

Comment: Can you edit clarify your text. I cannot understand what you're trying to say here.